# How can I tell if prerender.io is running correctly on modulus.io?

Tags: meteor, seo, prerender, modulus.io

**UPDATE**

I am able to install prerender on the modulus server now. BUT there is a problem with where to place the prerender token:

```
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', 'YOUR_TOKEN'));
```

Where in the .demeteorized node app does this line go?

---

I am running a meteor app on modulus.io I have installed the `https://github.com/prerender/prerender-node` package. The tests pass locally to run phantom.js. Meaning, it puts the page together, with all `meta` tags, `alt` for `img`s, `title`, page content and links.

Once modulus deploy is run, it shows `/.demeteorized/package.json`:

```
{ ...
 "dependencies": {
    ...
    "prerender-node": "https://registry.npmjs.org/prerender-node/-/prerender-node-1.0.6.tgz",
    ...
  } 
  ...
"PrerenderIO": {
    "token": "mYg3n3rAt3dTo0KeN"
}

}
```

In `main.js`, file contents:

```
process.argv.splice(2, 0, 'program.json');
process.chdir(require('path').join(__dirname, 'programs', 'server'));
require('./programs/server/boot.js');
```

The logs in prerender.io show:

```
> appName@0.0.1 start /mnt/app
> node main.js

Found package.json: ./package.json
Start script specified in package.json: node main.js
Initializing Node.js 0.10.36
Now using node v0.10.36
Running command: npm start
```

Is this all that is needed to run prerender service on modulus? What am I missing?

Comment: Does prerender.io need to be installed on the modulus server separately? Or does it get installed like all the other packages do in the package.json file?

Comment: Redeployed and 'prerender-node@1.0.6 node_modules/prerender-node' is an installed module like the rest.

Comment: I am still not sure if it is running

Comment: Please log into Prerender.io right now and re-generate a new token. Someone can use your token to cache pages into your account and cost you money since you published it here. Did you add the app.use(require('prerender-node')) in the place that you have express catching routes?

Comment: @Prerender.io mYg3n3rAt3dTo0KeN is not the real token. :) I did not add app.use(...). I should place in routes.js file?

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thanks for pointing that out :) Yes it should be placed before you set up your routes. Feel free to email me at todd@prerender.io and I'd be happy to help out more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the app to run properly after it was demeteorized. I was getting multiple errors on various npm packages when I attempted to launch the node app.

I ended up dropping modulus and prerender and used digital ocean with phantomjs and spiderable. Deployed via mup. All good seo works.